# Как получить имя вызывающей метод переменной?

Tags: java, переменные, рефлексия

Есть ли какой-то способ получить имя переменной, которая вызывает метод?
`average_deviation = $file.read.range.Float(0, 1);`
Мне нужно, чтобы в текстовый файл с событиями была внесена запись имя_переменной = значение.

```
private static boolean read()
{   
    MyFile $file = new MyFile(path, MyFile.action.read);
    try
    {
        feeding_times = $file.read.range.Int(1, 6);
        combinations = $file.read.range.Int(1, 10);                 
        stack = $file.read.range.Int(1, 6);
        int a = $file.read.range.Int(25, 600);
        if ( a%25 == 0)
            max_portion_size = a;
        else 
            return $file.read.ERROR();
        average_deviation = $file.read.range.Float(0, 1);
        favorite_tolerance = $file.read.range.Float(0, 1);
        previously_used_tolerance = $file.read.range.Float(0, 1);
        allow_essential_aminos_only = $file.read.single.Boolean();
        food_exceptions = $file.read.single.splitLineByLineToArray("§");
    } catch (NullPointerException ex)
    {   DetectCallingMethodException e = new DetectCallingMethodException();
        e.initCause(ex);
        Report.NullPointerException(ex, e);
        return $file.read.ERROR();          }
    return $file.read.OK();
}
```

Comment: Покажите код вашего класса

Comment: Вам хочется странного, такое обычно не нужно. Имена переменных во время выполнения не существуют (за редкими исключениями) и не доступны через рефлексию. (Кроме того, переменные не вызывают вовсе ничего.) Почему бы не использовать просто строку?

Comment: Я вот тоже читал, что компилятор имён переменных не хранит - ему это не надо.

Comment: Переменные не вызывают методы.

Comment: Переменная принимает значение, возвращаемое методом. Какая разница? Смысл понятен.